# I can't use FILTER with ARRAYFORMULA in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I realize that there are multiple questions with this title, but I don't understand the answers to them, or it is not directly related to my issue.

I'm trying to avoid manually "dragging" a formula to duplicate it for each row.

The formula looks like this

```
=FILTER(Companies!A$2:C, Companies!A$2:A="USD", Companies!B$2:B=D2)
```

and it works as well

But when I apply `ARRAYFORMULA` it shows the same result for each row

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(ISBLANK(C2:C),, FILTER(Companies!A$2:C, Companies!A$2:A="USD", Companies!B$2:B=D2:D)))
```

I've shared the spreadsheet with all data

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15m0nz2JWrVTu6fZj22Zdu1wnF3q7OVTA25DEl2xMR_k/edit?usp=sharing

I understand that Filter is an arrayformula but I can't understand how I can get appropriate data from another tab.

Comment: whats the desired output?

Comment: > I'm trying to avoid manually "dragging" a formula to duplicate it for each row

You can duplicate the formula by Ctrl + (arrow) to go to the end of the sheet; then Ctrl + C to copy. Navigate to the destination and Ctrl + V to paste the formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try in **E2**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(C2:C&D2:D, 
 {Companies!A2:A&Companies!B2:B, Companies!C2:C}, 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

---

try in **F2**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(E2:E, 'U Companies'!A2:C, {2,3}, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you very much. I forget that I can use array in filters of vlookup

Comment: Done. Thank you again. I've spending 6 hours on this task with no result

Comment: I found how to donate you. 15 bucks